# How to broadcast or send a single value to multiple processes (but not all of them)?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, broadcast

What I'm trying to do is to broadcast a value (my pivot) to a sub domain of my hypercube communicator.
So that for example process 0 sends to process 1,2 & 3 when process 4 sends to 4,5 & 6.
Does it require that I create communicators before hand or is there a way to do a broadcast/send to selected processes?

```
int broadcaster = 0;    
if(isBroadcaster)
{
    cout << "rank " << mpiRank << " currentd:" << currentd << " selecting pivot: " << pivot << endl;
    pivot = currentValues[0];
    broadcaster = mpiRank;
}

//TODO: Broadcast to processes 0 to 4 only.
//here, MPI_COMM_HYPERCUBE contains process 0 to 8
MPI_Bcast(&pivot, 1, MPI_INT, broadcaster, MPI_COMM_HYPERCUBE);
```

Comment: An alternative to the (sub-)communicators suggested by @WesleyBland would be to use one of MPI's virtual topologies, probably a graph topology.  It's a while since I used those so can't drag a proper answer together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution probably is to use `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` to break up your processes into sub-communicators. That *is* the way of describing communication domains.

The `MPI_GROUP` object is used for describing groups, but for the most part can't be used to perform communication.

Another option would be to use `MPI_ALLTOALLV`. That's pretty nasty though, and lots of overkill.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure creating communicators was the way to go. It confirms it. 
I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[mpi_comm_split](http://www.open-mpi.org/~jsquyres/www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.2/man3/MPI_Comm_split.3.php)** but if the group members change too often you have to repeat this.

Another solution (dirty but effective in my opinion) would *be broadcasting something like a process mask before issuing a compute command*. So process 0 will broadcast an array of 8 bool like values with true being set only for mask[1](http://www.open-mpi.org/~jsquyres/www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.2/man3/MPI_Comm_split.3.php), mask[2], mask[3] ...

Comment: I think i like the idea of creating communicators in the case of the hypercube. Thanks! (can't upvote you yet, too newbie here, sorry).